# How to add IFRAME in SilverLight?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0

How do I add IFrame in a Silverlight 4.0 User control ?

And I want a button on the control that refreshes the IFrame.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely want an IFrame in the HTML page (contrary to what the other answers suggest) you could obtain access to the IFrame in [Silverlight by using the HTML Bridge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221359%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: This is not contrary to what the other answers say.  This is exactly what we're saying, but we're suggesting not to use it.

Answer (score 2):

To render HTML on top of silverlight, you have to use WindowLess mode. This is a configuration in the object tag. Then you'll need to manually program your IFrame to float in the correct location using javascript or the bridge provided by Silverlight. You can use a commercial control like Robaticus suggested or figure it out on your own.

Either way, none of these options work for Mac. So if you're developing for Windows only, then you're ok. Anyone using Mac will not see any HTML float on top of Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about the Mac.  Was not aware of this, and can use this as further argument not to use this hack.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [WebBrowser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to display IFrame content in Silverlight. Or check this link it will also help you. - [How to use iFrame tag in XAML Silverlight 4?](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/213069/502964.aspx#502964)

Answer (score 1):

The iframe tag is HTML, not Silverlight.  If you have an out-of-browser Silverlight application, you could potentially use the WebBrowser control, but this is not available for in-browser applications.

There is an approach out there where you can essentially make a DIV on your hosting page appear overtop of your Silverlight application, but, in my experience, this is very hard to control, and the visual results are less-than-ideal.

Additionally, there are a few commercial components that do HTML rendering, but they all seem to use the same approach of a floating DIV, and they are not as reliable as I would like to see them.